# Is there a limit on the import in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am new to Google Cloud SQL and have created a schema on Cloud SQL. I have imported (using import in google GUI) a CSV file of 5M(unique) rows into this table but only 0.5M rows show up. Not sure if there is a limit I am missing something.
P.S. I also have enough free storage available.

Comment: When you mentioned 5M and 0.5M rows, does that mean 5 million and 500k rows?

Comment: @RobertG yes, 5 million and 500k rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there's a row size limit of 65kb for mySQL even if your storage is capable of storing larger rows. This may be the reason why your table only displays a limited number of rows. There are several factors that affect the row size limit like storage engine (InnoDB/MyISAM) and page header and trailer data used by the storage engine. This is based on the mySQL documentation on [row size limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits).

Since Cloud SQL supports current and previous versions of mySQL (as well as PostgreSQL and SQL Server), the row size limit for those versions are also applicable.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Is there a way to increase this limit? 
Also, can Cloud BigQuery be used in place of Cloud SQL? I mean does it also have a limit? 
Or would you suggest some other alternate?

Comment: @sakshamsingh, since this is a mySQL implementation I'm afraid that this is already fixed unless changed by mySQL themselves. Yes you can use BigQuery for this as it has a larger [row size limit of 100mb](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs).